# Output 0..5 voltage controlled by PC

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, dac

A piece of lab equipment (an image intensifier) is controlled by voltage in the range of 0..5V (current is expected to be in the range of 10 mA; desired resolution is around 12 bits; no frequency requirements since we won't be changing the voltage much). The internal voltage of the intensifier is set to `500V + (850V - 500V) / 5V * Vc`. I would like to make it a part of a larger apparatus, all controlled by a PC. Therefore, I need the PC to control a DAC.

What would be a simple way to do that? Should I look for a microcontroller with a real DAC (not PWM) in 5V range? (Those I found seem to be limited to 3.3V - perhaps I didn't look in the right places?) Should I buy a simpler microcontroller and a separate DAC controlled by I2C? Use a 3.3V DAC with an operational amplifier?

It is not a problem for me to write a PC or uC program, but I don't have any successful circuit building experience, so I would like to optimize for less building complexity.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99053/discussion-on-question-by-aitap-output-0-5-voltage-controlled-by-pc).  Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://www.eeci.com/dac-4up.htm) is one example of a USB to 12 bit DAC for around $80.

> Typical applications include variable air damper control, blower and
>   motor speed control, light level control, audio sound level control,
>   motion control, water/fluid/air valve position control,
>   variable-frequency drive (VFD) motor control, 4-20ma loop control,
>   solenoid position control and hundreds of other applications. Connects
>   to USB - Powered from USB port 4 channels of 10 bit Digital to Analog
>   (1,024 increments in output level) with DAC-4U10 4 channels of 12 bit
>   Digital to Analog (4,096 increments in output level) with DAC-4U12
>   Selectable reference voltage - allows for 0 to 3.3v, 0 to 5v or user
>   supplied voltage output ranges Available with high precision voltage
>   reference pre-installed. Allows for (0 to 1.2v), (0 to 2.048v - .5mV
>   per increment), (0 to 2.5v), (0 to 3v) or (0 to 4.096v - 1mV per
>   increment) output ranges

Comment: We ended up buying the USB DAC. I also ordered an ATtiny85 clone pre-flashed with a USB bootloader and an I2C display to gain some experience in communicating between USB and I2C peripherals in my spare time.

Answer (score 1):

Not having much successful circuit building experience doesn't sound hugely promising but here goes for a potential solution to your problem.

If you have a microcontroller lying around already then an R2R ladder DAC with a unity gain voltage buffer at it's output would do the job for not needing to change often/quickly, being cheap and being controllable form a PC. You could just about do this with an Arduino UNO and Arduino IDE as you don't have to worry too much about how slow the digitalWrite() method is.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdIKyJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>